# Excel Vba - Calling a sheet with a variable sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I've been coding in VBA for some time, but this one has really stumped me.

I'm creating a workbook which creates technical certificates for machines. We have varying templates depending on the machine type and I am attempting to get my code to select the correct sheet from a user input and then populate the sheet. FYI these template sheets will be hidden and the user can only interact with the userforms.

Heres the code that is failing:

```
Machine = MachineType.Text '<-- input from userform, for example Machine = "Vertex 251"

Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Machine) '<--- select that machine's sheet
wsCopy.Copy '<--Run time Error 1004: Method copy of object_worksheet failed
```

I've tried numerous different types including just `sheets(machine).copy` or

```
Sheets(machine).activate
Activesheet.copy
```

but nothing has worked so far - I cannot tell if I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Any help would be be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must unhide the sheet before copying it (at least to a new workbook as lturner notes) - you can then re-hide it

```
Dim shtTemplate as Worksheet, sheetWasHidden As Boolean
Set shtTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Machine)

'handle the case where the sheet to be copied is Hidden
If shtTemplate.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
    shtTemplate.Visible = xlSheetVisible
     sheetWasHidden = True
End If

shtTemplate.Copy
If sheetWasHidden Then shtTemplate.Visible = xlSheetHidden 're-hide if needed
```

Comment: To mention: you can copy the worksheet whilst it's hidden, if you provide a destination for the copied worksheet (although the new worksheet will also be hidden).

Comment: that's done it! I wasn't sure if the hiding has anything to do with it but this has worked! thanks very much!

Comment: As for you last comment - I did try and set the destination ie copy after:= sheets(.... etc but that did not work either. Does the level of hidden make a difference here? i have my sheets set to xlveryhidden.

Comment: Yup, works like a charm when i change it to xlsheethidden. every day is a school day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you have the worksheet object and use the `Copy` method, Excel seems to be making assumptions (or not) about where you want to put the new sheet. I pretty much always use the `After` option to define where the new sheet should go.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Set wsCopy = ActiveSheet
    wsCopy.Copy After:=wsCopy
End Sub
```